# Sharing two PSN accounts problem

Tags: ps4, psn

the I'll try to describe the problem I currently have with my account which I currently share with my friend.

So I have a main account which is set to primary on my console which has a game. I logged on to this main account from my friends console and he couldn't pay any of the games until I made the account primary on his console. Of course, to do this I had to deactivate primary on my console.

Now my friend can play all my games, but the question is it possible for me to run my own games from another account activated on my PS4? Because right now I have locks on all of my games if I login from another account (because primary is not set, it's set on my friends console).

I'm asking this because I already tried to give my account to another friend, and we were able to play the same games (he used his account and I used my another account, not the one which has the games bought) even without activating the primary account on the console. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot share games with other accounts on the same system unless your account has been activated as Primary. Similarly, if you activate your account as Primary on your own console, your friend will lost access to your games.

There is no way around this, and this process is in place for a reason: to stop exactly what you're trying to do. Sony doesn't want to make it easy to share digital games, so you're stuck.

You're left with two options:

1. Keep deactivating / activating your account on your console and your friends console. Eventually, Sony any block you for activating too many times.
2. Just buy whatever game(s) your friend wants to play and make your life easier.

Comment: Think can also goes web to buy game?